# How to do a image link with a post method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<a <%= link_to "Basket", product_items_path(product_id: product), :method => :post %><%= image_tag"/assets/addToBasket.png" %></a>
```

This displays the link that will add the item to the basket, along with the image below. 
How would I turn the image into a clickable link that will use a link and the post method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link_to` can take a block like this.

```
<%= link_to product_items_path(product_id: product), method: :post do %>
  <%= image_tag "addToBasket.png" %>
<% end %>
```